# How can one make a second x-axis for a plot of data points?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to graph a group of data points. I want to add another x-axis on top of the plot with different units than the original one (Want wavelength instead of log(frequency). I have seen lots of other examples on here, but they all have to do with a continuous plot, and I can't quite figure out how to use the .twinx() function for a graph with data points. Here is what I have so far for the plot:

```
plt.plot([x_values], [y_values], 'ks')
plt.text(x3, y3, u'\u2193', fontname='STIXGeneral', size=20,
         va='top', ha='center', clip_on=True, color='k')
plt.text(x5, y5, u'\u2193', fontname='STIXGeneral', size=20,
         va='top', ha='center', clip_on=True, color='k')
plt.axis([x_0, x_max, y_0, y_max])
plt.ylabel('$log(frequency) \circ Luminosity)$')
plt.xlabel('$log(frequency)$')
plt.title('C1')
plt.show
```

I am new to python, so any suggestions would be great!

Comment: To have another x axis, you would need `twiny` instead of `twinx`.

Comment: Ok, but I have only seen twiny or twinx in general as used for a continuous plot, not for data points. When I use it it tries to connect my points, which is not helpful.

Comment: whether the plot shows points or connected lines is **completely** independent of the use of twin axes.

Comment: Can you help me out and tell me how to display just points then?

Comment: You already have the command to plot points in your code. I added a duplicate where points are used.